# How to create Semaphore between HTML elements loaded async

Tags: javascript, html, semaphore

I have in an HTML page, an element that appears several times, and running the same JS.
Problem is, I want it to do a specific function only if it was the first one to run it (his siblings never ran it - YET).

I need semaphore to sync between them.
I am unable to know how to declare a variable and  to do semaphore in this way in JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of approaches.

You need to put a flag *somewhere*. In the absence of anything else, you can put it on `window`, but use a name that's unlikely to conflict with anything else.

Then the JavaScript is quite straightforward:

```
if (!window.myUniqueNameFlag) {
    window.myUniqueNameFlag = true;
    // Do your processing
}
```

But again, putting things on `window` is not ideal if you can avoid it, although it's **very** common practice. (Any variable you declare at global scope with `var`¹ is a property of `window`, as is any function you declare at global scope.)

If your function is already declared at global scope (and therefore already occupying a global identifer / window property), you can do this to avoid creating a second identifer. Instead of:

```
function foo() {
    // ...your processing...
}
```

Do this:

```
var foo = (function() {
    var flag = false;

    function foo() {
        if (!flag) {
            flag = true;
            // ...your processing...
        }
    }

    return foo;
})();
```

That looks complicated, but it's not really: It defines and immediately invokes an anonymous function, within which it defines a variable and a nested function, then it returns the nested function's reference and assigns it to the `foo` variable. You can call `foo` and you'll get the nested function. The nested function has an *enduring reference* to the `flag` variable because it's a [closure over the variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html), but no one else can see it. It's completely private.

A **third** option is to just use a flag on the function object itself:

```
function foo() {
    if (!foo.flag) {
        foo.flag = true;
        // ...do your processing...
    }
 }
```

Functions are just objects with the ability to be called, so you can add properties to them.

---

¹ Variables declared at global scope with `let` or `const` are globals, but do not become properties of `window`.

Comment: It is not atomic operation. theoretically, both elements can pass the if condition before then assign the variable

Comment: @oshafran: JavaScript on browsers is guaranteed to be single-threaded barring the use of the new [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) stuff, which requires explicit syntax. So the above **is** atomic on a browser. If you were using some other environment, and *if* that environment were multi-threaded, you'd use the synchronization mechanisms provided by the environment. But you said this browser-based, so none are needed.