# Make a method pause until another property is ready

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an object used for interacting with an IndexedDB.  It has a property ready that changes to 2 when the database has finished opening.  How can I tell the read method to wait until `this.ready == 2`?

```
var db = {
    open: function() {//a callback sets this.ready to 2 when the database has been successfully opened},

    ready: 0,

    read: function() {
        if(!this.ready == 2) {//pause until this.ready == 2}

        ...
    }
}
```

Should I write a function using `setTimeout` to check this.ready every 100 milliseconds or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346694/how-to-implement-a-lock-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timeout (actually, probably an interval that cancels itself) is the only good way in JavaScript to "wait" for something.  Otherwise, because there's only a single thread, you end up blocking all other JS Execution in the browser.  The other option would be to have something call your function when the status becomes a 2 (use a callback).

The "waiting" is approached like so:

```
var myWait = setInterval(function () {
  if (status == 2) {
    clearInterval(myWait);

    myFunction();
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

normally any pausing would need to be done in a different thread but im very new to javascript so it could be different.  but u can also try to have the function return whatever data u need then feed it into function2
function2(function1())

Answer (score 0):

using getters and setters on the object you can define a custom callback when the ready is set, then run you code if / when it is set to 2
[read here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @g.d.d.c - You should switch your logic around to use callbacks. You already have a `open` callback (at least according to your code example), so why not simply invoke `read` when your `open` callback is done? Then there is no need to make a blocking operation in your script.