# Calling a ajax function on page load and on click of button

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javascript file containing a ajax function with parameter x.
I cannot reveal the function.I want to call the function on page load and on a button click.Also there is a for loop on the function for displaying the variable 10 times i.e,
`for(i=0;i<10;i++)`.

The code for that button is :

HTML file

```
<html>
 <title>Call web service</title>
  <head>
   <script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script type = "text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     window.onload=function()
     {
       Webservice(1)('onload');    //call 1 where webservice is ajax function 

      }


    </script>     
   </head>
 <body>
   <input id="button"  type = "button" name = "button" value = "Call Webservice" onClick = "Webservice(5)"/>
 </body>

</html>
```

Right now what I am getting is the onload function is getting overridden when I click the button whereas I want the outputs of both the functions to be displayed simultaneously
So please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the method skeleton

Comment: what is the result of the function?

Comment: The result of the function is that we get a 1 & 1 at start then on 2nd iteration we get 9 & 0 as loop starts to execute and executes for 10 times till 9 & 9. But when iteration of onload goes till 3rd loop and I click button onclick gets called and onload gets overwritten and stops.

Comment: am little confused. What do you mean by simultaneously? After the page loads only u are going to click the button . So how can it be simultaneous> What i am missing?

Comment: why not create another function with a different name and same content, so on load calls one thing and button click calls another. If you need the data throughout, you can make the variables global and refer them.

Comment: i think what is happening is that the onload function is taking so long that before it is completed, the button tries to execute the function.

Comment: By simultaneously I mean that on clicking of button if onload has completed 4 loops then it should continue to execute and also onclick loop should start to execute and both outputs should be displayed in alert messages as there is a alert message within the for loop to display the variavle.      Sorry for confusion.                    Aashray I too think the same thing but am not finding any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
function f1() {
    //what you need to do
}
function f2() {
    //Do the same thing here also
}
```

This being your JS, in onload, call `f1()` and for button click call `f2()`. If you want `f1()` to execute before `f2()`, i suggest you look into locks here:

[How to implement a lock in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346694/how-to-implement-a-lock-in-javascript)

Comment: then you need to implement a lock on the function. That is the only way to make sure that to function executes the entire duration.

Answer (score 1):

Your javaScript code should be something like this:

```
var fn = function fn(x) {
  // Do something
}

$(function() {
  var someValue;

  // someValue = ...

  // Call function once document is loaded
  fn(someValue);
  // Bind function as a callback to button click
  $('#button').on('click', function(event) {
    fn(someValue);
  });
});
```