# call ajax function onload and on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to show report base on the election date. when I call the function showReport() on form load is working, but it's not working when I call that function on button click.

Report members
[image]

```
<script>
function showReport(){
   var from = $('#from').val();
   var to = $('#to').val();
   var str = $('#str').val();
 if(from == '' && to == '')
 {
    var from = '$from';
    var to = '$to';
 }
$.ajax({
    url: "crm_data_report.php?type="+str+"&from="+from+"&to="+to,
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var date = [];
    var value = [];
    for(var i in data)
    {
    date.push(data[i].date);
    value.push(data[i].value);
    }
    var color = Chart.helpers.color;
    var chartdata = {
    labels: date,
    datasets :
    [
    {
    label: 'Members',
    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: value
    }
    ]
    };
    var ctx = $("#mycanvas");
    var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartdata
    });
    },
    error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
    });
}
```

**The code I called the function on load and on button click.**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   showReport();
});
$('#filter').click(function(){
    showReport();
});
</script>
```

Comment: whats the error when calling it in `button click`? and check `button click` is working

Comment: The error is ajax can not send the data to the url: "crm_data_report.php?type="+str+"&from="+from+"&to="+to.

Comment: will you please show the html code of the button ?

Comment: <button id='filter'>Filtter<button/>

Comment: Is this html code your actual code line that you have in your program? Because this markup for the button is wrong. The end tag should be </button>. Or is it just a typo here?

Comment: Sorry I typed wrong.

Comment: Not related to the question though...is it possible to send an ajax request from one html page and receive the response in another html page ?

Comment: I just fix it. Thank you. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a ajax function on page load and on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470898/calling-a-ajax-function-on-page-load-and-on-click-of-button)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code block with this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#filter').click(function(){
        showReport();
    });    
})
```

> Its a very common issue you are binding the click event when the
>   button is not available to dom yet , so you have to bind it when dom
>   tree is ready.

Comment: Or just move the click event handler  call into the above $(document).ready() handler.

Comment: have any jsfiddle ?

Comment: I don't have jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is on a hunch, there's nothing wrong with your code. Could you please try

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   showReport();
   $('#filter').click(function(){
    showReport();
   });
});
</script>
```

It is possible that the DOM has not loaded completely (#filter element) when you are attaching the click handler to it.

Comment: I don't know the idea why it's not working. :( I try this also but the report not show by selection date, it's show only from load.