# Lock a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, locking

I have a JavaScript function like the following.

```
function changeTheDom(var1, var2, var3) {
    // Use DWR to get some server information
    // In the DWR callback, add a element to DOM
}
```

This function is called in a couple of places in the page. Sometimes, in a loop. It's important that the elements be added to the DOM in the order that the `changeTheDom` function is called.

I originally tried adding `DWREngine.setAsync(false);` to the beginning of my function and `DWREngine.setAsync(true);` to the end of my function. While this worked, it was causing utter craziness on the rest of the page.

So I am wondering if there is a way to lock the `changeTheDom` function. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346694/how-to-implement-a-lock-in-javascript) but I couldn't really follow the `else` loop or how the `lockingFunction` was intended to be called.

Any help understanding that post or just making a locking procedure would be appreciated.

Comment: Just so I understand the question correctly: you want to trigger an asynchronous function inside your function and wait for it to finish and then execute the rest of your function?

Comment: Yeah. Haha. As mentioned, turning off the async within the function caused a lot of chaos.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to lock anything. The cleanest way is always to adapt to the asynchronous nature of your code. So if you have an asynchronous function, use a callback. In your particular case I would suggest that you split your function up in one part that is executed before the asych call and one part that is executed afterwards:

```
function changeTheDomBefore(var1, var2, var3) {
    //some code
    //...
    asyncFunction(function(result){
        //this will be executed when the asynchronous function is done
        changeTheDomAfter(var1, var2, var2, result); 
    });
}

function changeTheDomAfter(var1, var2, var3, asynchResult) {
    //more code
    //...
}
```

`asyncFunction` is the asynchronous function which, in this example, takes one argument - the callback function, which then calls your second `changeTheDom` function.

Comment: I am not sure I see how this solves the problem. When you say the `asyncFunction`, do you mean the DWR call? Because the problem is that the callbacks of that are called out of order.

Comment: Hmm...that's why I asked in the comment section. If this doesn't help you then I guess I'm still not sure what the problem is that you're experiencing.

Comment: I basically am calling an async function in my method, but don't want it to be async. Because the elements have to be added to the DOM in the order the function is called. But turning off the async for the DWR causes issues. Hence why I thought locking might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got what you mean and I decided to create another answer, which is hopefully more helpful.

To preserve order when dealing with multiple asynchronous function calls, you could write a simple Queue class:

```
function Queue(){
    var queue = [];
    this.add = function(func, data) {
        queue.push({func:func,data:data});
        if (queue.length === 1) {
            go();
        }
    };
    function go() {
        if (queue.length > 0) {
            var func = queue[0].func,
                data = queue[0].data;

            //example of an async call with callback
            async(function() {
                    func.apply(this, arguments);
                    queue.shift();
                    go();            
            });
        }
    }
};

var queue = new Queue();

function doit(data){
    queue.add(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }, data);
}


for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    doit({
        json: JSON.stringify({
            index: i
        }),
        delay: 1 - i / 10.0
    });
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JveFQ/1/)**

So everytime you invoke your async function, you call `queue.add()` which adds your function in the queue and ensures that it will only execute when everything else in the queue is finished.

Comment: It doesn't look like the Fiddle worked. I actually ended up doing a hack fix that only works for my particular problem. If you delete your answers, I'll delete the question (can't delete when there are answers).

Comment: why would you delete it? maybe it's helpful for others. and the fiddle works for me. you click "with queue" and it prints out everything in order. if you click on "without queue", the output gets mixed up.

Comment: Clicking the buttons do nothing for me. I am in Firefox.

Comment: Just tried it in Firefox. Still works for me. Do have the console enabled?